# HTML. href mailto задать текст письма

Tags: html, outlook

Необходимо чтобы по ссылке формировалось письмо с заданным текстом. НО! нужно чтобы в тексте письма была гифка!

```
<a href=mailto:?subject=Спасибо&body=/uploads/docs/thx/thx.html"> GO! </a>
```

в боди я указал путь к html документу где в html тегах указано

```
<img src="thx.gif">
```

но может просто путь к гифке прописать? Но суть в том, что он воспринимает этот путь как сообщение... каким образом реализовать? Спасибо заранее!
PS возможно еще есть простой способ вести статистику нажатий ?

Comment: Т.е. гифка нужна только для учета нажатий?

Comment: Плохая идея. Все нормальные почтовики блокируют подобное. А статистику нажатий чего надо вести? Нажатий на ссылку?

Comment: Гифка должна быть в тексте письма(именно в тексте, а не вложенный фаил). Весь процесс происходит на корпоративном сайте с корпоративной почтой. Статистику нажатий на ссылку.

Comment: @FlatOMG тогда вообще не понимаю, зачем вам гифка, чтобы считать нажатия О.о Либо Вы что-то недоговариваете, либо ничего не слышали про JS и т.п. И в чем всё-таки вопрос: вставить гифку или считать нажатия?

Comment: мне не нужно считать нажатия гифкой. Гифка находится в тексте письма (сообщение) вопрос в том как сделать так, чтобы она туда попадала. Я вроде корректно описал все... А подсчет нажатий (на ссылку) - это доп вопросик про возможность реализации.

Comment: Вставить HTML код в строку body в mailto нельзя. Вернее есть хитрые манипуляции, но они не во всех браузерах срабатывают. И уж точно нельзя сослаться на внешний файл-шаблона...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вставить HTML код, в том числе тег картинки или ссылку на файл внешнего html-шаблона, в строку body в mailto нельзя.

Вот, что написано в [RFC 6068](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6068)

> The special  "body" indicates that the associated 
> is the body of the message.  The "body" field value is intended to
> contain the content for the first text/plain body part of the
> message.  The "body" pseudo header field is primarily intended for
> the generation of short text messages for automatic processing (such
> as "subscribe" messages for mailing lists), not for general MIME
> bodies.

Другими словами строка в body может быть только в формате "text/plain", а не MIME HTML.

Как вариант, можно предлагать по ссылке скачивать файл формата msg (во всеми заготовленными шаблонами), который будет автоматически открываться почтовым клиентом пользователя, и который уже можно отправлять как письмо. Но это извращение.